Westjet airport lounge access
I've got some WestJet lounge vouchers available on my WestJet rewards account (from my WestJet credit card) and was going to use them to grab dinner before my flight. However I am flying from Calgary to Heathrow, and it seems the Westjet lounge is only available for domestic travellers. Their website lists a bunch of other lounges, saying this:


Platinum, Gold and Silver WestJet Rewards members may be eligible for    complimentary lounge access based on their tier benefits and
each    lounges entry requirement. See individual lounge access below.
Guests seated in Business on our Boeing 787-9 Dreamliner also enjoy    complimentary lounge access.
To receive access, the above guests must    present a valid boarding pass displaying a WestJet flight number.


There's nothing mentioned about vouchers, and the YYC international lounge description just says "Save 10% off the walk-in price when you present a valid WestJet boarding pass"; nothing about free access so I assume it's not available.
In fact, all the Canadian lounge descriptions only say something about a small discount. Some of the European ones say things like "Complimentary access for Business Class, Platinum, Gold, and Silver Tier members with vouchers." I am none of those things, just a poor man with a voucher lol
Does anyone have any experience with these vouchers? Are they able to get me in for free anywhere other than Westjet's own domestic lounge at YYC?

Which specific type of lounge voucher -- do you know the program, e.g. Priority Pass?

What does the voucher say? Who issued it? What credit card do you have which gave you those vouchers?

@Meizzajanor it’s from WestJet through their RBC Mastercard

at most airports, it's not just that you're a different kind of traveller domestic vs international, it's the you're in a different terminal and therefore a different lounge.  I know Air Canada used to give me domestic lounge access vouchers and I never got a chance to use any of them because I never fly Air Canada (or anyone else) domestically.

@KateGregory yes different terminal and different security gates. The international lounges are run by someone else, it's just the domestic one that's run by WJ
